# How to get drive name from drive letter?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I have searched internet but couldn't find answer,how can I get drive name from drive letter on c++ for windows?I mean if I say G:\ it has to give me the name of pen drive.Ex:Removable Disk.

Comment: Show your effort so far (ie. code you have so far that gets some drive letters and tries to display the drive names). in the [MCVE] format..

Comment: I have found a site with two examples: https://codetwee.blogspot.com/2020/05/finding-volume-name-or-label-using.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is as simple as calling the [`GetVolumeInformation` API function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364993.aspx). You pass in the drive letter as the path name (*e.g.*, `G:\`), and the function fills a buffer containing the volume name (along with other information, if you are interested in any of that).

Here is the code required to retrieve the volume name for the G:\ drive. The volume name is placed into the `szVolumeName` buffer:

```
WCHAR szVolumeName[MAX_PATH];
BOOL bSucceeded = GetVolumeInformationW(L"G:\\",
                                        szVolumeName,
                                        MAX_PATH,
                                        NULL,
                                        NULL,
                                        NULL,
                                        NULL,
                                        0);
```

If you want any of the other information while you're calling the function, like the volume's DOS serial number, the file system name, etc., then you can change the parameters from `NULL` to the appropriate buffers.

Comment: How do I get the drive names that appear in the Windows Explorer rather than the volume names? E.g., a drive that appears in the Explorer as "DVD RW Drive" has an szVolumeName of "Windows", a drive that appears as "Garmin eTrex 30" has an szVolumeName of "GARMIN". Thanks!

Comment: I found practical examples at https://codetwee.blogspot.com/2020/05/finding-volume-name-or-label-using.html